# Connect Treeview Child Node to Database Details

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

I'm working with VB.net 2010 & have a Treeview that's being populated from a MySQL table via a Dataset in the Form1_Load.

The treeview loads the test data from the database table fine but I want to be able to click a treeview Child Node & display the matching data from the MySQL table Row inside multiple textbox.

I know I need to have a textbox for each table Cell in a Row but I can't figure out how to connect the table Row ID column to the treeview (child node). My table ID column is named UserID in the screenshot below.

I also know I need to add code to the TreeView1_AfterSelect. I think I might be able to use the treeview node Tag to connect to the table UserID column, but I'm just not sure about the code.

My treeview root node is set in design view.

I only have a Binding Navigator & Datagrid on the Form while testing the treeview/table-details, those will eventually be removed from the Form.

Here's some background on how I'm [loading the treeview with my test data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043768/populate-treeview-from-sql-server-database) from the MySQL table.

Here's some screenshots of my Table data & the VB.NET Form, this site won't let me post images.

- [MySQL Table Data](http://i58.tinypic.com/11ijrmd.png)
- [VB.NET Form image](http://i57.tinypic.com/2lu89zc.png)

I've been trying to get this to work for at least a week with no luck. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```vb
Private Sub AddNode(parentNode As String, nodeText As String)
    Dim node As New List(Of TreeNode)
    node.AddRange(TreeView1.Nodes.Find(parentNode, True))
    If Not node.Any Then
      '' '' ''This is the Parent Treeview Node
      node.Add(TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(parentNode, parentNode))
    End If
    '' '' ''This is the Child Treeview Node
    node.Add(TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(parentNode).Nodes.Add(nodeText, nodeText))
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load       
   'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet.Table44' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table44TableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Table44)
    For Each dr As DataRow In Database1DataSet.Table44.Rows
      AddNode(dr("ParentNode").ToString, dr("ChildNode").ToString)
    Next
    TreeView1.ExpandAll()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database structure doesn't quite make sense to me.  Can there be more than one city per state?  Or is it always one user and one city. It's not clear.

Anyway, you can use the node's Key parameter to set the Name property, and see what you clicked on:

```vb
Private Sub AddNode(parentNode As String, nodeText As String, userID As String)
  Dim node As New List(Of TreeNode)
  node.AddRange(TreeView1.Nodes.Find(parentNode, True))
  If Not node.Any Then
    node.Add(TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(parentNode, parentNode))
  End If
  node.Add(TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(parentNode).Nodes.Add(userID, nodeText))
End Sub
```

Then in your AfterSelect event, see if your key is a number:

```vb
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) _
                                  Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
  Dim userID As Integer = 0
  If Integer.TryParse(e.Node.Name, userID) Then
    ' do something with userID
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, that Integer.TryParse worked great. I used the BindingSource.Position = (userID - 1) in the treeview_afterselect to finish connecting the treeview to the Table Data Details (textboxes).